# Separate SIM cards for different users?

Tags: multi-user, dual-sim

is it possible to assign the different SIM cards in a dual-sim phone to different users in Android?
-- I tried this with my Moto G4 Plus phone, but did not manage to set this up.  It seems that the SIM card settings are global and not per user.

What I'd like to achieve is having one user profile and SIM card to private usage, and the other SIM card assigned to a separate user for my work.

Is this a systematic Android limitation, or is it only that the Moto G4 Plus does not support this kind of setup?

Thank you.